# css border-bottom property does not work in Chrome when using full screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

I noticed that css border-bottom property does not work in Chrome.

So far I've checked on IE 10 and Mozilla. Works fine on these browsers. It works on Chrome when I'm not using full screen though.

```
#sync2 .item{
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:25%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to an example? Or a fiddle?

Comment: can you specify in which situation border doesn't appear?

Comment: header {
 border-bottom: 3px #f4f4f4 solid;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line all the way at the top of your html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Edit:
It's likely the same bug as the one documented [here](http://uxdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2011/03/webkit-colspan-table-border-bug.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also find that issue in chrome and opera i resolved it like This

first you set all the border

```
border:1px solid white;
```

and next you remove the top , left and right border

```
border-left:0px;
border-right:0px;
border-top:0px;
```